# How do I find bases for $M_{2 \times 2}$ vector space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I'm asked to find two different bases for $M_{2 \times 2}$.I have not worked with vectorspaces that consists of matrices before. How many matrices are there in the basis for this type of vectorspace? And how do I find two different bases for this type of vector room? There is unfortunately no information about this in my book.

Comment: It's no different from $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a vector space.  It doesn't matter that the elements are written in a square instead of a line.

Comment: Never thought about that before. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of $2\times 2$ matrices
\begin{equation*} B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\} \end{equation*}
and note that this set is linearly independent, spans the set of $2\times 2$ matrices and, continuing the idea from the comment, has four members. Now you just have to find another set of four vectors (matrices) that is distinct from this one and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now!

Comment: You're welcome!